# Zend Framework 1: Troubleshoot 404 Pages for Zend Translated pages

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have migrated my Zend Framework 1 site to a new server.

The site populates and renders with no errors apart from one issue related to Translated Pages.

The once working translated pages return 404 errors, and when you click on the home page url - it returns only english.

The site base URL is english, and has two other languages.

The database and the backend of the CMS has all the original content, however, when we render the translated URL's they return as a 404.

Each language is routed to its own domain, managed by the application.ini file.

Could anyone let me know what this issue could be?

Server background - moved from Debian 7 to 9
Php running on new server is 7.0 - could this be the issue? (Old server it was low 5.x)

I have checked all based URL's all are set as they were before. In fact all scripts and folders are exactly the same, including the folder structure.

No php errors to display - none show.

Only repeat error is as follows but i dont think this is related:

PHP Deprecated:  iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated in /var/www/DOMAINNAME.com/library/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 302

Line to refers to

iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply.

We ended up finding out the problem, and it was not PHP related. We are still running php.7.0

The issue was actually related to a Google Maps API that we excluded from running. This was related to Google Maps, which is not in use, however, for some reason the way this was set up it needed to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework 1 doesn’t support PHP7, and its EOL was on 28 September 2016.
Said so, you can encounter lots of problem due to this incompatibility.

You could try to fix that problem maybe using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504224/iconv-set-encoding-deprecated-broke-needed-function), but the advice is to consider a refactoring of your application also to avoid security issues.